# Java - How to check if there is a value inside an ArrayList that is a value of a key in a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
if (!mainMethods.matrix.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mainMethods.matrix.values().size(); i++) {
        if (mainMethods.matrix.containsValue(getArrayList()[i].getValue().toString().contains(textValue.getText()))) {
            String errorTitle = "Impossível completar a operação.";
            String errorMessage = "Não é possível adicionar um valor de chave repetido.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), errorMessage, errorTitle, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);            
        }
    }
```

There is this HashMap called "matrix", and it has lots of keys. The value of every key is an ArrayList that has its own values. Considering this, I can't find a way to test whether there is a specic value inside the ArrayList-Values, because if I pass an String argument to the method ".containsValue()" of the HashMap, the method will find an ArrayList object and the test will be false. Therefore I must do something rather insane, just like I did in the example. As you can see, there's no such thing like "getArrayList()", or "getValue()". It's a very complicated situation and I tried to explain my point with "Pseudo-Code".

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you try simplifying your code.  I don't imagine you really what the code to do what you have written.  Try breaking down the code into shorter lines of code and see what they are doing in a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this ought to work:

```
private <K, V> V getValueIfKeyContains(final Map<List<K>, V> map, final K desiredKey) {
    for (final Entry<List<K>, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().contains(desiredKey)) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So you loop over the `Map` and check whether each key contains the `desiredKey`.

I would **strongly recommend** two things:

1. Don't use mutable values as keys in a `Map`. This causes massive issues as they can change *after* they are added to the `Map`.
2. Don't use `List` if you want to check `contains`. This is an `O(n)` operation, i.e. it takes time proportional to the size of the `List`. It has to loop over every element in the `List` until it finds the right one. Use a `Set` and the operation becomes `O(1)`, i.e. constant time.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing. Change your data structure as...

Old one is:

```
HashMap <Key, ArrayList>
```

Change to

`HashMap<Key, HashMap<Value in ArrayList at index[i], Value in ArrayList at index[i]>>`.

This is assuming you have immutable objects inside the arrayList. So now once you get an object using key. You can again search in inner map using its keys.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll try to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterator and check each arraylist individually:

```
Iterator it = mainMethod.matrix.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    If(pairs.getValue().contains(your value)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for-each` loop to iterate over your `ArrayList`s (I've assumed they hold `String`s) and use their `contains()` method to test if a value is present within or not.

```
if (!mainMethods.matrix.isEmpty()) {
  for (List<String> list : mainMethods.matrix.values()) {
    if (list.contains(textValue.getText())) {
      String errorTitle="Impossível completar a operação.";
      String errorMessage="Não é possível adicionar um valor de chave repetido.";
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        getParent(), errorMessage, errorTitle, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
  }
}
```

If possible switch to using a `Set` instead of a `List` as searching a set is many times faster. But sets won't allow you to have duplicates. So, choose what suits your requirements better.